# Proving that $||f(x)||$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

Suppose $f=(f_1,...,f_m)$ be a vector valued function which is continuous on $[a,b]$. How can I show that $||f(x)||$ is also Riemann integrable? Any answers will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Depending on what theorems you have, the norm is just a composition and sum of continuous functions. This it is continuous and hence Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(x)=\Vert f(x)\Vert$ is itself a continuous function (composition of continuous functions is continuous) hence it is Riemann integrable.